# Filtering by time in Slack API

Tags: slack, slack-api

Is there some way to filter the data by date? I don't need to get the entire event log every time. I would like to get data for the last 15, 20, 30 minutes or for the last 1, 2, 3 days. Is it possible? I've seen something similar to this api - files.list.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, Slack APIs does not provide a mechanism to filter data unless it is mentioned in the API's documentation.